# String interpolation with date to string conversion in scala

Tags: python, scala

I'm trying to figure out how to make string interpolation with date cast to string. Here is the sample, in python I do

```py
def get_the_last_n_days(days):
    return f"'{str(datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days))}'"
```

Basically, it will return the current date subtract by the number of given days. For instance, considering the date `2021-04-08`:

- If the given number is 1, the output will be the string`2021-04-08`;
- If the given number is 8, the output will be the string `2021-03-31`;

Again, in python I would something like:

```py
print(f"I'm married since {get_the_last_n_days(0)}")
```

To interpolate the string, the statement above would print something like `I'm married since 2021-04-08`

I've tried some approach but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import java.time.LocalDate

def daysAgo(n: Long) : LocalDate =
  LocalDate.now().minusDays(n)

s"I'm vaccinated since ${daysAgo(9)}."
//res0: String = I'm vaccinated since 2021-03-29.
```